# How to change format of certain citation tag

Tags: bibliographies

I have an `@online` reference and set the `url` and `urldate` fields accordingly. However, those two don't show up in my bibliography. So far I used `note={\url{...}, accessed ...},` as field, but this creates a lot of redundancy.

I currently use `\usepackage{cite}` and `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`.

How can I change the format in the bibliography for this certain citation tag (`@online`)?

Comment: Can you please tell us which citation/bibliography package (`cite`, `natbib`, `jurabib`, `biblatex`, ...) your are using and which bibliography style (with BibTeX-based approaches that would be the argument of `\bibliographystyle`, with `biblatex` the `style` option)? A solution will crucially depend on your current bibliography setup. Currently, the question is tagged `biblatex`, but with `biblatex` all standard styles and most custom styles show the `url` and `urldate` fields for `@online` entries at all times, so I doubt you actually use `biblatex`.

Comment: If the `url`/`urldate` field doesn't seem to be working, chances are your style simple doesn't support that field. Many of the BibTeX standard styles hail from the late eighties and simply have no notion of URLs. In those cases it is easiest to switch to a different (more modern) style if there are no external forces compelling you to stick to such a style.

Comment: @moewe I've updated my question

Comment: `ieeetr` is one of the BibTeX standard styles and has essentially not been updated since 1988. It does not know anything about URLs. If you are not forced to use the style, you could pick a style from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/urlbst or if you like IEEE style `IEEEtran`. Or you could make the switch to `biblatex` directly https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864 (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/35864).